# ETH Transaction‏ failed - paid Value, Transaction Fee and Gas Price - why?

Tags: failed-transaction

I've made the following Transaction‏ yesterday: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc08e7a5dc8a9e5d7c0e07fce50b1f7052630bccb578100aa3c1fcff6401aa65a

I understand why I paid the fee and gas price, but why didn't I get back the value (0.2ETH)? to whom should I return or what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 0.2 ETH has never left your wallet because the transaction was reverted. However, you paid some gas fees for this failed transaction (0.0655 ~$250)